# Pulling data from DE on multiple values of a variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I have a requirement wherein I have to query a database for the following condition.

> Database [Report Pull] has let us say 2 columns
>   CustomerID   ReportDt

I have have to find all the customers who have not have a record in last 30 days but have a record exactly (today - 30 ) among other conditions.

```
Select Condition on [Report Pull] PR
and cast(PR.ReportDt as Date) = cast(getdate()-30 as date)
and not exists (
                select   PR2.*
                from [Report Pull] PR2
                where 1=1
                and cast(PR2.ReportDt as Date) > cast(getdate()-30 as date)
                and PR2.CustomerId = PR.CustomerId
)
```

Now i want to pull customers such that

```
cast(getdate()-30 as date) is mod30 = 0
AND at the same time
cast(PR2.ReportDt as Date) > cast(getdate()-30 as date)

Next 
cast(getdate()-60 as date) is mod30 = 0
AND at the same time
cast(PR2.ReportDt as Date) > cast(getdate()-60 as date)
that is no report pulled in last 60 days
```

and so on for every 30 days. This is because the db can have multiple records of report pull.
I know it is a bit confusing, but please help me. :)

> Please note we cannot declare any variable in SQL. The DB is Salesforce Marketing CLoud aka ExactTarget

Comment: Sorry, I've just read over your question again. Could you share what you want the final output of this query should to look like? "And so on" for how long?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find all customers whose records were pulled on every 30*x days? In perpetuity? So 30 days 60 days 90 days and son on?

```
SELECT 
CustomerID, 
ReportDt
FROM [Report Pull]
WHERE MOD(DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD (DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), ReportDt),30) = 0
```